# Python multiprocessing pool : How to check if a specific worker has finished

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to log the times that multiprocessing.pool workers take individually , I'm creating the processes as follows

```
p = multiprocessing.pool(processes=4,initializer=Initializer,initargs=(arg1,)
```

In my `Initializer` function , I can log the time when each worker starts. I'm looking for a similar hook/function that is called when a worker finishes, is there anything like this?